# Is there a reason to encapsulate if I am the only one using my code?

Tags: encapsulation

I understand that we encapsulate data to prevent things from being accessed that don't need to be accessed by developers working with my code. However I only program as a hobby and do not release any of code to be used by other people. I still encapsulate, but it mostly just seems to me like I'm just doing it for the sake of good policy and building the habit. So, is there any reason to encapsulate data when I know I am the only one who will be using my code?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "encapsulation"? Why not program in a good style regardless of the scope of your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encapsulation not only about hiding data.
It is also about hiding details of implementation.

When such details are hidden, that forces you to use defined class API and the class is only who can change it inside.
So just imagine a situation, when you opened all methods to any class interested in them and you have a function that performs some calculations. And you've just realized that you want to replace it because the logic is not right, or you want to perform some complicated calculations.

In such cases sometimes you have to change all the places across your application to change the result instead of changing it in only one place, in API, that you provided.

So don't make everything public, it leads to strong coupling and pain during update process.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulation is not only creating "getters" and "setters", but also exposing a sort of API to access the data (if needed).

Encapsulation lets you keep access to the data in one place and allow you to manage it in a more "abstract" way, reducing errors and making your code more maintainable.

If your personal projects are simple and small, you can do whatever you feel like in order to produce fast what you need, but bear in mind the consequences ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think unnecessary data access can happen only by third party developers. It can happen by you as well right? When you allow direct access to data through access rights on variables/properties, whoever is working with that, be it you, or someone else may end up creating bugs by accessing data directly.